# rounded corner not working in frameset

Tags: css

is there a way to show rounded corner in IE frameset?
here is an example:

index.html:

```
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<frameset rows="*,64" style="margin:0; padding: 0;"  framespacing="0">
    <frame name="main" src="test.html" frameborder="0" border="0"  framespacing="0" marginwidth="0" />
    <frame name="header" scrolling="no" noresize target="main" src="template.html"  framespacing="0" />
</frameset>
</html>
```

and test.html:

```
<html>
<head><title></title>

<style>
.listing td {
    -moz-border-radius: 14px;
    border-radius: 14px;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table class="listing">
<tr>
<td>rounded corner not work in frame!</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

look at test.html and then index.html. it not works in frame! (IE9)

do not tell me that Do not use frame or blah blah.. i should use it and do not wish to use div solution. it is a demo page and need frameset.

Comment: `frameset`s are deprecated in HTML5.

Comment: IE8 doesn't support rounded corners

Comment: I'm afraid the only answer is: "don't use a frameset".

Comment: am I said anything about html5 or ie8?

Comment: Don't use TABLEs either.

Comment: and yet I'm afraid you can't achieve rounded corners on a `frameset` and you'll need to use the good new `iframe`s and a bunch of `div`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you've set a doctype for each file.

```
<!doctype html>
```

your pages render in quirksmode without a doctype, with a doctype they'll render in IE 9 mode and should show the rounded corners